# How does IO monad work in System.Random

Tags: haskell, io, monads

```
import System.Random

main = do
  g <- newStdGen
  a <-take 5 (randoms g :: [Double])
  return ()
```

So this code doesn't work because apparently what I'm assigning to a has type [Double] instead of IO [Double] but I thought that you can't escape from IO ever? So how come I seemed to have escaped from IO even though g is type IO? I'm still confused on how IO monads work inside do notation.

Comment: Check that type of `g`!   `g <- newStdGen`  `:type g` yields `g :: StdGen`.  You can't escape, but you you can get values and perform pure computations.

Comment: but why doesn't line 2 (in do) compile

Comment: line 2 does not compile because `take 5 (randoms g :: [Double])` does not return an `IO` (or *monadic*) value.  If you change the line to `let a = take 5 (randoms g :: [Double])` then it should compile alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't escape from `IO`, but inside a `do` block you're not actually *escaping* per se.

Loosely: when you write `g <- newStdGen` in a `do` block, you can then use `g` later in the block as if it just had type `StdGen`, instead of `IO StdGen`.  At the end of the block, whatever you return will be wrapped back up in `IO`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `let a =` instead of `a <-` since the RHS is a pure value.

```
import System.Random

main = do
  g <- newStdGen
  let a = take 5 (randoms g :: [Double])
  print a
```